# В c# есть что-нибудь на подобии typedef как в си?

Tags: c#

```
typedef void(*fun)();

public void buttonClick(Button but,fun f) { but.Click += (s, a) => f; }
```

Comment: Делегаты? (Еще 5 символов)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен делегат Action

```
public void buttonClick(Button but, Action f) 
{ 
     but.Click += (s, a) => f(); 
}
```